# Manipulating StringBuilder() string

Tags: java

I am trying to search for regular expressions in a string created by StringBuilder() as follows

```
public String config( String langage ) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (dir_user+"/.prochic/"+langage));

    //System.out.println(getAbsolutePath());
    String         line = null;
    StringBuilder  stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String         ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    try {
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) {
        stringBuilder.append( line );
        stringBuilder.append( ls );
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();

    } finally {
    reader.close();
    }
};
```

and then

```
String text=config(langage);
```

However, I can't do something like

```
System.out.println(text[5]);
```

How can I access (or print) the different components (characters) of my string?

Comment: You can use `new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(language), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` however you may want to process each line as you read it instead. e.g. `File.lines`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`.charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)):

```
System.out.println(text.charAt(5));
```